# Titanium make an apk without launching an emulator or anything else

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Using the appc ti commands, how can i make an apk file but not launch an emulator?

All my emulators don't work - i'm using tishadow to load into my phone - so it is just irritating when the appc command brings up a useless emulator.

I don't see any useful commands from -h ~ --no-launch still launches an emulator, so i'm not even sure what it is meant to accomplish!

Answer (score 3):

Go into the project folder and run:

> appc run -p android -b

this will generate an apk in

> build/andorid/bin/

-p is the platform
-b is build only

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of build command in the CLI reference on the documentation page of Appcelerator: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-43294287_AppceleratorCommand-LineInterfaceReference-AndroidBuildOptions

For example

> Name of the device or emulator to install the application to.

```
-C, --device-id <name>
```

Or

> Output directory (used when target is dist-playstore).

```
-O, --output-dir <dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command should do the trick:

```
appc ti build --platform android --deploy-type production --target dist-playstore --android-sdk "~/Library/android-sdk-macosx" --output-dir "~/Documents/APK" --keystore "~/Downloads/keystore/Untitled" --store-password "youratorepw" --key-password "yourkeypass"
```